# Some questions about these two sentences: What did I have and What have I

Tags: grammaticality, difference

I saw people leave their comments in some strange videos on Youtube:

> What did I have just watched?
>
> What have I just watched?

Is there any difference between the two sentences?
Which one is more grammatical?

Comment: The first one is wrong, but it looks like they meant something like "What did I just watch?" The second one is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What did I have watched?

The sentence is ungrammatical. The words "did" and "have" are auxiliary verbs. You don't use another auxiliary verb with did.  You use the auxiliary verb did with the base of a verb to form a question in the simple past tense. So the correct sentence is:

What did I just watch?

The other question (What have I just watched?) is grammatical - it's in the present perfect tense.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is not correct.

> What did I just watch?
>
> What have I just watched?

The above are the right ways to say this and there is no difference between the two in meaning.

Comment: Welcome to ELL!  Your answer is correct, but it might be a lot more useful if it included more of an explanation about why the first sentence was not correct, and how the other two possibilities are formed.

Comment: Thank you and good point, I'll remember this in future. Looks like Khan has explained it sufficiently for this one.